# Mutate variable using lagged calculate variable

Tags: r, purrr

I want to calculate the real values based on a start value and a growth rate using mutate and accumulate, but I haven't succeeded.

In a loop it would look like this (although this is not an option as I want to do this for a grouped `tibble` with lots of grouping variables).

```
data <- tibble(Nominal = c(100, 104, 108), GR = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03), Real = c(1000, NA, NA))

for (i in 1:2) {
  data$Real[i+1] = data$Real[i] * (1 + data$GR[i+1])  
}
```

Any hints on how to do this with `mutate()` and `accumulate()`? Here something I tried but it doesn't work:

```
calc_chain <- function(prev, new, GR) {
  ifelse(is.na(new), prev * (1 + GR), new)
}   

data %>% 
   mutate(Real = accumulate(Real, calc_chain))
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `accumulate2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(Real = unlist(accumulate2(Real[-1], 
       GR[-1], ~ ..1 * (1 + ..3), .init = first(Real))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Nominal    GR  Real
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     100  0.01 1000 
2     104  0.02 1020 
3     108  0.03 1051.
```

---

Or with `accumulate`

```
data %>%
   mutate(Real = unlist(accumulate(lead(GR),  ~ ..1  * (1 + ..2), 
      .init =  first(Real))[row_number()]))
```

-output

```
  Nominal    GR  Real
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     100  0.01 1000 
2     104  0.02 1020 
3     108  0.03 1051.
```